# EEVEE - Volumetric Thickness

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine

I have been using the procedural cloud node from

https://www.blendernation.com/2018/11/06/free-procedural-cloud-system-for-eevee-real-time/

and I have not been able to control the actual density / thickness no matter what I try. Below is the image of the closest I can achieve in dissapearing the pole within the volumetric material. If someone could give me any guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Ive tried numerous alterations for 2 days, I wouldnt know where to start in listing the things ive tried.

Comment: You could start by showing the current nodes you have for your material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volumetric Clipping! The whole time I was fidelling with nodes when the solution was under properties panel under volumetric clipping start/end... Jesus I hope someone who has this issue finds this post!